# What is "Imaginary" diff change type?

Tags: c#, diff, diffplex

I'm testing [DiffPlex](https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex) and I saw [this](https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex/blob/201825eeb34e7c1f011dbbcac2d283b71c0f4f70/DiffPlex/DiffBuilder/Model/DiffPiece.cs#L11) enum:

```
public enum ChangeType
{
    Unchanged,
    Deleted,
    Inserted,
    Imaginary,
    Modified
}
```

All other ChangeTypes makes sense, but I cannot understand the meaning of "Imaginary" enum here, and I cannot find in Google about this in Diff languages, so I wonder if is something specific for DiffPlex.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand now. When comparing side by side diffs, if we removed a line in left side, this line will not exists in right side. So the UI will show this fact as a "imaginary" line in right side.

Comment: I think its about whole line is changed, you can see the unit tests and understand its open source, its also the default ChangeType for DiffPiece when the empty constructor is called
https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex/blob/201825eeb34e7c1f011dbbcac2d283b71c0f4f70/DiffPlex/DiffBuilder/Model/DiffPiece.cs